# Child divs inside parent div are not vertically aligning

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the white child divs to align vertically in the centre of the red parent div (while ensuring the red div stays aligned in the centre of the grandparent pink div).

I've tried displaying the red parent div to be a table cell but this shifted the red div to the left of the grandparent pink div and didn't align the vertically divs anyway. Also tried different types of positioning.

Is there an easier way of achieving this without the use of flex boxes? Thanks for any assistance.

```css
.sections-stretched {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background: #f0f;
    margin: 0 auto 50px auto;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 50px 0;
}

.stretched-container {
    max-width: 960px;
    height: auto;
    background: #f00;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.home-summary {
    width: 26%;
    height: auto;
    background: #fff;
    margin-right: 11%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

.no-padding-or-margin {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.clear{ clear: both; }
```

```html
    <section class="sections-stretched">
        <div class="stretched-container">
            <div class="home-summary">
                <h4>eirh erergerge ergergiuerhgier</h4>
                <p>ergergerg erg ergerg ergergergegeg erg ergerg ergergergegeg, etc</p>
            </div>
            <div class="home-summary">
                text here lorem imsup cla bla bla bla bla bla bla blal bla blw bowrnbuehrbuehr beurohertext here lorem imsup cla bla bla bla bla bla bla blal bla blw bowrnbuehrbuehr beuroher
            </div>
            <div class="home-summary no-padding-or-margin">
                text here lorem imsup cla bla
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: remove float wich kills display, then vertical-align will be avalaible for your inline-block elements. Else give a try to flex :)

Comment: Is there a reason to avoid flex? I'm guessing some sort of outdated browser support?

Comment: thanks all. Didn't realise it was as simple as replacing the float with vertical align and then ensuring no white space between the elements. Preferred to see an alternative to flexboxes as I'm not too familiar with them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `float` and white-space between the elements so that `width: 26%; margin-right: 11%` will consume 100% of the parent, and use `vertical-align: middle;`

```css
.sections-stretched {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background: #f0f;
    margin: 0 auto 50px auto;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 50px 0;
}

.stretched-container {
    max-width: 960px;
    height: auto;
    background: #f00;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.home-summary {
    width: 26%;
    height: auto;
    background: #fff;
    margin-right: 11%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.no-padding-or-margin {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.clear{ clear: both; }
```

```html
<section class="sections-stretched">
        <div class="stretched-container">
            <div class="home-summary">
                <h4>eirh erergerge ergergiuerhgier</h4>
                <p>ergergerg erg ergerg ergergergegeg erg ergerg ergergergegeg, etc</p>
            </div><div class="home-summary">
                text here lorem imsup cla bla bla bla bla bla bla blal bla blw bowrnbuehrbuehr beurohertext here lorem imsup cla bla bla bla bla bla bla blal bla blw bowrnbuehrbuehr beuroher
            </div><div class="home-summary no-padding-or-margin">
                text here lorem imsup cla bla
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may remove `float` and use `vertical-align`. (`float` override `inline-block` display)

eventually `text-align-last` to justify the boxes

```css
.sections-stretched {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: #f0f;
  margin: 0 auto 50px auto;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.stretched-container {
  max-width: 960px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0 5%;
  background: #f00;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  text-align-last: justify;
}

.home-summary {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 26%;
  background: #fff;
}

.no-padding-or-margin {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<section class="sections-stretched">
  <div class="stretched-container">
    <div class="home-summary">
      <h4>eirh erergerge ergergiuerhgier</h4>
      <p>ergergerg erg ergerg ergergergegeg erg ergerg ergergergegeg, etc</p>
    </div>
    <div class="home-summary">
      text here lorem imsup cla bla bla bla bla bla bla blal bla blw bowrnbuehrbuehr beurohertext here lorem imsup cla bla bla bla bla bla bla blal bla blw bowrnbuehrbuehr beuroher
    </div>
    <div class="home-summary no-padding-or-margin">
      text here lorem imsup cla bla
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

flex can also make this easier to manage :   https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.sections-stretched {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: #f0f;
  margin: 0 auto 50px auto;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.stretched-container {
  max-width: 960px;
  height: auto;
  background: #f00;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  /* added flex */
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:space-around
}

.home-summary {
/* reduced  to minimal */
  width: 26%;
  background: #fff;
}

.no-padding-or-margin {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.clear {
  display:none; /* or remove from html when using flex */;
}
```

```html
<section class="sections-stretched">
  <div class="stretched-container">
    <div class="home-summary">
      <h4>eirh erergerge ergergiuerhgier</h4>
      <p>ergergerg erg ergerg ergergergegeg erg ergerg ergergergegeg, etc</p>
    </div>
    <div class="home-summary">
      text here lorem imsup cla bla bla bla bla bla bla blal bla blw bowrnbuehrbuehr beurohertext here lorem imsup cla bla bla bla bla bla bla blal bla blw bowrnbuehrbuehr beuroher
    </div>
    <div class="home-summary no-padding-or-margin">
      text here lorem imsup cla bla
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

If it is to center content inside the white boxes, flex can be inbricated :

```css
.sections-stretched {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: #f0f;
  margin: 0 auto 50px auto;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.stretched-container {
  max-width: 960px;
  height: auto;
  background: #f00;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  /* added flex */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around
}

.home-summary {
  /* reduced  to minimal */
  width: 26%;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: column
}

.no-padding-or-margin {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.clear {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="sections-stretched">
  <div class="stretched-container">
    <div class="home-summary">
      <h4>eirh erergerge ergergiuerhgier</h4>
      <p>ergergerg erg ergerg ergergergegeg erg ergerg ergergergegeg, etc</p>
    </div>
    <div class="home-summary">
      text here lorem imsup cla bla bla bla bla bla bla blal bla blw bowrnbuehrbuehr beurohertext here lorem imsup cla bla bla bla bla bla bla blal bla blw bowrnbuehrbuehr beuroher
    </div>
    <div class="home-summary no-padding-or-margin">
      text here lorem imsup cla bla
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: thanks. I'll definitely have a more thorough look into flex boxes sometime!